# How to move the point in the direction that indicates the normal?

Tags: vectors

There is a point (for example $P(1,1,0)$) and the normal (for example, $n_2(0, 1, 0)$). I need to move the point to the specified distance in the direction that indicates the normal.

Picture:

[image]

The point can be any, the normal can indicate any direction.

More precisely, I need the opposite direction. But I think I will be able to change the direction.

Comment: In your case the length of the normal vector is $1$. So if you want to move $P$ in the normal's direction with a distance of $5$ for example, just add $5n$ to $P$, resulting in $(1,6,0)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\vec p=(p_x,p_y,p_z)$ is the given point and $\vec n =(n_1,n_2,n_3)$ with $||\vec n  ||=1$ is the **normalized** direction vector, than the point $\vec x$ at distance $d$ from $\vec p$ in the direction $\vec n$ is given by:
$$
\vec x= \vec p + d \vec n
$$